# Homebrew not installing correctly

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh, sonoma

I was installing homebrew through the .pkg to install GNU Emacs, and it did not run after installation. I ran `brew help` and it outputted `zsh: command not found: brew`. Command Line Developer Tools *were* installed before installation of homebrew. The PKG file was from the official site. I am running MacOS 14.0 on a 2020 M1 MacBook Air. [image: picture of the terminal window]

Comment: You have not explained exactly all the steps you did for installation, so it's hard to diagnose. And of course: Die you manually check, whether the directory containing `brew` is in your PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is a problem with your $PATH - as there are some setup steps you have to run once the install completed.

Let's check to see if that's it... Run these commands:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew update
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew update
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew doctor
```

If the doctor says to do things, do them and post a comment here. I am assuming you installed homebrew into the default location and missed this part of the install:

> ==> Next steps:
>
> - Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
>
>   `(echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users/<whatever your obfuscated user path is>/.zprofile`
>   `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

Comment: Output `Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!
Warning: Homebrew's "bin" was not found in your PATH.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`. Most likely, that is the case, although moving the path has been a recurring problem for me.

Comment: Yes - see my edit - you need to append the results of `(echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"')` to your .zprofile or back it up and start with a new .zprofile file...

Comment: Are you using OhMyZsh or some other setup? @AverageTerminalUser

Comment: No, I am using the default mac zsh, but your previous answer worked! `brew help` outputted the full help list, and all brew commands work!